# Copy datas from PostgreSQL to CSV file

Tags: django, database, postgresql, digital-ocean

I have a Django application on server with PostgreSQL database and now I want to copy all datas in this database to some CSV file on my local storage. I'm running this command:

`db_name=# \COPY table_name TO '\Users\username\Desktop\applicants.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

But this command returns me `Permission denied` error. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Did the user that run the command have the write permission on that folder/file?

Comment: I don't know, @Renato, I guess no. How can user on server reach my local files...

Comment: So the server doesn't run on your local machine... you have to choose a path on the server and then download the file

Comment: @Renato, so, friend, how can I download the file from server ?

Comment: scp from the command line or any FTP client, such FileZilla or similar

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem first of all I created a dump CSV file in project on server. Because, I have an easy access to my files on server, but not to my local files. After creating that dump file, I used following command:

`\copy (SELECT * FROM some_table) to '/home/username/project_folder/dumpfile.csv' with csv;`

Now all datas in my table was copied to `dumpfile.csv`. At the end I just downloaded this CSV file via FileZille as my friend @Renato said.